# SWT Layout creating

Tags: eclipse, swt

I'm quite new to creating layout using SWT. This is what I have to create
[image]

And this is my try so far : 
[image]

Code :

```
   private void createContents(final Shell shell) {
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,true));

    /// Side Panel
    Composite sideComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    sideComposite.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL | SWT.BORDER ));
    Label codeLabel = new Label(sideComposite, SWT.NONE);
    codeLabel.setText("Folders");

    // Create list of folders
    Composite foldersComposite = new Composite(sideComposite, SWT.NONE);
    foldersComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,true));
    createFoldersComposite(foldersComposite);

    // Create tags
    Composite tagsComposite = new Composite(sideComposite, SWT.NONE);
    tagsComposite.setLayout(new RowLayout());
    createTagsComposte(tagsComposite);

    /// .Side Panel

    /// Main Panel
    Composite mainComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    mainComposite.setLayout(new RowLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));

    // Create search field
    Composite searchComposite = new Composite(mainComposite, SWT.NONE);
    searchComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,true));

    Label searchLabel = new Label(searchComposite, SWT.NONE);
    searchLabel.setText("Search");
    GridData gridData = new GridData();
    gridData.horizontalSpan = 1;
    searchLabel.setLayoutData(gridData);

    Text searchText = new Text(mainComposite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    searchLabel.setLayoutData(gridData);

    // Create search result
    Composite resultComposite = new Composite(mainComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    resultComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,true));
    createResultComposite(resultComposite);

    // Code Review
    Text codeText = new Text(mainComposite, SWT.MULTI | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.BORDER );
    codeText.setSize(500, 500);


    /// .Main Panel
}
```

Question: How can I fix my existing code to have the exact layout I want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be helpful to break this down into separate widgets, instead of having a monolithic control that tries to handle the layout for everything at once.  This allows you to nail down the layout on each separate component correctly, then building them up a piece at a time to get the overall layout you want.

This is especially noticeable in your sample code - you're creating a `Composite` called `searchComposite` with a two-column `GridLayout`, and you're adding `searchLabel` to that composite.  But you're adding `searchText` to `mainComposite`, which I think is not what you intended.

Instead, I would create a `SearchControl` that had a two-column `GridLayout` containing a `Label` and a `Text`.  The `GridData` on the `Text` should `grabExcessHorizontalSpace` to fill the remainder of the control.

I would suggest getting more familiar with `GridLayout` and `GridData`.  Don't be afraid to experiment.  For example, you're always passing `true` to the `GridLayout` constructor, which will make column match widths.  While this is perfectly reasonable, it doesn't match the layout you've sketched where some columns are wider than each other.  Also, I would suggest looking at `GridDataFactory`.  It will turn all the `GridData` fiddling into a one-liner.

Comment: " Break this down to separate widgets ? " Do you mean I should create another function ? 
The GridDataFactory is really great :)